# The location.href will not be lanuched when the value of input box isn't changed in javascript, why?

Tags: javascript

The following code display a input box, and location.href will be lanuched when I enter a new value and click "Ok" button.
But location.href will not be lanuched when I don't input new value and click "Ok" button directly, why?

BTW, I test the code in both IE and Firefox,and I get the same result!

```
$('.CssRename').click(function () {
    var fileName = GetHiddenFilename(this);        
    var defaultname = fileName.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
    defaultname = decodeURIComponent(defaultname);
    var name = prompt("Please input new file name", defaultname);

    if (name) {
        location.href = "actionrenamesingle.htm?fullfilename=" + fileName
                        + "&newfileorfoldername=" + name
                        + "&origurl=" + GetOrigUrl();
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the user input? What's the HTML look like? What does `GetHiddenFilename()` and `GetOrigUrl()` look like? What's the expected behavior? What are you currently seeing? We need more info before we can even begin to help.

Comment: Probably the `defaultname` value is null?

Comment: The input is filename,  "var fileName = GetHiddenFilename(this)" return a filename

Comment: The defaultname isn't null!

Comment: The defaultname isn't null! and it can be displayed in input box